# Deleted, disabled users in Exchange vs loosing phone numbers, contact information

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, exchange

We have `Exchange 2010` and we're using `Exchange` and `AD` for storing `phone numbers`, `contact information` etc. This is also synchronized with `SharePoint`. What's the best approach of keeping that contact information when person leaves company. Theoretically their account is disabled 5 minutes after they are out so disabled accounts get removed from GAL, Address Lists etc. What's the best approach for this scenario? The person may need to be contacted for other purposes.. maybe simple changing password to something hard?

Comment: How about having HR keep that information in the employee file?

Comment: Probably they could do that. But since we like to keep everything electronic I have to solve it this way as well. I guess telling CEO, sorry you will have to keep HR if you want to call some guy isn't really going to work.

Comment: This sounds like a case for an HR database of some sort. While you certainly could use AD to keep and store that information I don't see that as the best solution. That being said, is it the case that you want ex-employees to show up in the GAL on the off chance that someone may need to contact them in the future?

Comment: Yes, they need to stay in the AD/Exchange for contact purposes. Just in case. One option is to disable the user and create an external contact with "copied" information, and put him into some special Address List or so.

Comment: I sympathise with the whole 'having to tell the CEO "no" thing' but Exchange isn't a HR database no matter how much *anyone's* CEO pouts and insists it is, any more than a 40-something IT geek like me can suddenly run 100 metres faster than Usain Bolt just because I stamped my feet, pouted and said "but I really really want to." MikeAWood's suggestion is a good work around, but the actual solution is to get an actual HR solution of some sort in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the information into a Mail Contact.  That way the information is still available to the users, but doesn't need to be bound to an account.  There might be an easy solution in Powershell to do this.  Certainly something you could script.

Comment: By global contact you mean internal Mail Contact. So basically disable account, and create a copy of it in Mail Contact?

Comment: Yes, I mistakingly put Global as I was in the middle of doing some Active Directory group management when I answered this. This way the information is available to your exec staff.  Maybe mark the entry with the term date in one of the fields so you can sort it and delete them as they get older.